# Strcpy() - Segmentation fault in C

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I am working on a lab assignment and we need to create a dictionary to hold some words and their pirate-speak equivalent.  I am able to read the file in, separate the words out as shown by the sscanf function, but I'm getting a segmentation fault when I use strcpy to store each word in their respective array: `strcpy(&eng[i], englishWord);`

I do not understand how to correct this problem. (Sorry if my code is ugly.  This is my first time programming in C.)

```
void CreateDictionary( char eng[], char pir[] ){
  char word[40];
  FILE* dictionary;

  const char *pirateWord;
  const char *englishWord;

  dictionary = fopen("english-to-pirate.txt", "r");
  if (dictionary == NULL){
    printf("Unable to open the dictionary file.\n");
  }
  else{
    //Setup dictionary
    int i = 0;

    while(fgets(word, sizeof word, dictionary) != '\0'){   
      //Split line using semicolon
      sscanf(word,"%[^;];%[^;]", englishWord, pirateWord);
      printf("%s : %s",englishWord, pirateWord);

      //put term in corresponding array
      strcpy(&eng[i], englishWord); //seg fault occuring here

      strcpy(&pir[i], pirateWord);
      i++;  
    }
  }
  fclose(dictionary);
}
```

This is where the function is being called:

```
int main( ) {
  char inFileName[100];
  char outFileName[100];
  FILE* inFile;
  FILE* outFile;
  char english[75] = {[0 ... 74] = '\0'};
  char pirate[75] = {[0 ... 74] = '\0'};

  CreateDictionary(english, pirate);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you realize, that `char english[75]` is not array of strings? It is  one string. So it is very strange that you are trying to put the dictionary into this one string. It looks like you need to use array of strings instead of array of characters.

Comment: I guess I didn't... That makes sense though.  Thank you for pointing that out.  I'm off to figure that part out now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no assigned memory associated with `englishWord, pirateWord` in which to put the scanned data.

Use `char pirateWord[sizeof word]; char englishWord[sizeof word];`

Always good to check the result of `sscanf()`

```
if (2 != sscanf(...)) FailedToScan();
```

Comment: This fixed my issue and I understand why the issue occurred now. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You must have memory (and enough memory) allocated for the destination pointer in strcpy.  Without seeing the calling code for CreateDictionary, it's not possible to diagnose what went wrong.

If the calling code doesn't allocate memory for eng[], you could consider using strdup instead of strcpy.  strdup will allocate the enough memory to hold the string.